# Tensorflow 2.x: call model inference using C/C++ API from inputs, allocated in GPU memory

Tags: gpu, tensorflow2.0, c-api

I’d like to use TensorFlow 2.13 in scientific simulation code, written in C++, via [C-API](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/lang_c).
The code runs simulation on GPU, so all necessary input data for the model are already placed on GPU too.

I need to prepare input for the model, that contains multiple TF_Tensors.

My question is: Is it possible to control, where to place TF_Tensor? Can I make it point to  existing on-GPU array to avoid CPU-to-GPU memory transfer?

If wrapping TF tensor around existing data is not possible,  would that be possible to copy memory within GPU?

I found [TF_AllocatorAttributes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/tf_tensor.h#L33) struct, that contains placement flag and it is used, for example, in [TF_AllocateTemp](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/c/kernels.h#L503),
but this function requires also `TF_OpKernelContext ctx`. Unfortunately it is not clear for me where to take it and is it safe at all to use it in C-API